# Famo.us POST method

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, famo.us

How do I make an `HTTP POST` request with `Famo.us` framework?
I wish it's `Utility` library would have one along with their `GET` method, but there isn't. Do I need to implement my own one then? How did you guys solve it with your form data uploads? Do you use third party libraries? The info on `Famo.us` forms data handling is quite scarce - I couldn't find anything, except the `InputSurface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Famo.us has no helper functions for making POST requests. HTTP requests aren't within the scope of what it is trying to achieve. You can either:

- use XMLHttpRequest directly
- include a helper library which provides a wrapper for making POST requests
- use some other ajax POST technique (such as submitting a form to an invisible iframe)

Comment: Thank you, Quantin. Would you recommend a way to display an HTML form? Should I add the elements to DOM?

Comment: If you want to display a form then you *have* to add it to the DOM.

Comment: Yes, of course :) Sorry. The way I do it now is I render it in a `Surface` and then invoke xhr request upon submit. Am I on the right track?